# Linking a Google Form to a SharePoint List (Office 365 Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I am trying to link a Google Form which will be used to collect data for some data collection that I am doing. I am wondering if there is anyway that I can link the responses of my Google Form directly using Microsoft Flow to a SharePoint List instead of importing the whole Google Sheet to excel and upload it in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no connector between **Power Automate** and **Google forms**, so we couldn't link the responses of Google Form directly using Microsoft Flow.

[image]

List of supported connectors in Power Automate: https://flow.microsoft.com/connectors/